# Batch sending an email

Tags: email, batch-file

I am making a program using batch and upon a crash or an error it will make a text file called `debug.txt`. I need to know if there is a way of emailing this file automatically using batch to the following email address "`something@example.com`". `debug.txt` is in the same location as the batch file. Does anyone know a code I could use. It must not have any extra softwere.

Comment: I would remove the e-mail address form the question if I were you as it isn't needed for an answer anyway.

Comment: Since it's text, you could just email it as the body of a mail message. For example, `sendmail [options] [email_address] < debug.txt` and choose "options" for what you want for a subject, etc.

Comment: @Zabri is right. You shouldn't post your email in any public forum. It's a primary way of getting spammed heavily.

Comment: I know i shoudnt but if they click on my profile they can see it any way.

Comment: @09stephenb: I think only you can see it there. I definitely can't.

Comment: Ok thats good to know.

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 ultimate 32bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 3 options for you as of now:

**1.** The bottom line is there's no built-in way in batch, but there are third-party tools like blat etc. that can be called from a batch file, but as you have mentioned you don't want any extra software.

**2.** You can enable the installed SMTP Server of Windows. And then run a Powershell script:

```
$smtpServer = "system.abc.com"
$smtpFrom = "dontreply@abc.com"
$smtpTo = "something@abc.com"
$messageSubject = "Put your subject here"

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
$message.Subject = $messageSubject
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.Body = Get-Content debug.txt

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)
```

**3.** You can enable the installed SMTP Server of Windows. And then run a VBScript:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const FileToBeUsed = "debug.txt"
Dim objCDO1
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed, ForReading)
Set objCDO1 = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objCDO1.Textbody = f.ReadAll
f.Close
objCDO1.TO ="something@abc.com"
objCDO1.From = "dontreply@abc.com"
objCDO1.Subject = "Put your subject here"
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /sendusing") = 2 
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserver") = "system.abc.com"
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserverport") = 25 
objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Update     
objCDO1.Send
Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

As you have mentioned that you are using Windows 7 ultimate so both option 2 and 3 will work on your system very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use free tool like sendemail.exe http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/. Download and copy sendemail.exe to system path. This is only for simple internal SMTP messages. This cannot be used to send external messages unless your Exchange server is setup to send anonymous external messages. Almost all Exchange servers are not setup to do this.

You can use this simple routine in the batch script.

```
CALL:SENDEMAILALERT "From SMTP address" "To SMTP addresses" "Subject" "Message" "File to attach" "smtp.host.com:25"

:SENDEMAILALERT
SET SENDEMAILCMD=-f "%~1"
SET SENDEMAILCMD=%SENDEMAILCMD% -t "%~2"
SET SENDEMAILCMD=%SENDEMAILCMD% -u "%~3"
SET SENDEMAILCMD=%SENDEMAILCMD% -m "%~4"
SET SENDEMAILCMD=%SENDEMAILCMD% -a "%~5"
SET SENDEMAILCMD=%SENDEMAILCMD% -s "%~6"
SENDEMAIL %SENDEMAILCMD% >NUL 2>&1
SET SENDEMAILCMD=
GOTO:EOF
```

Comment: As I said in the question I need it not to include any extra software.